# How to drop a node on an empty dynatree

Tags: javascript, dynatree

I have two dynatrees on the same page. Tree 1 has various number of nodes, tree 2 is empty. I would like to drag a node from tree 1 and drop it on tree 2. Everything works fine while tree 2 is not empty. If tree 2 is empty, however, it is not working at all. Here is my code:

```
$('#tree1').dynatree({
    dnd: {
        onDragStart: function (node) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});

$('#tree2').dynatree({
    dnd: {
        onDragEnter: function (node, sourceNode) {
            return true;
        },
        onDrop: function (node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
            var copyNode = sourceNode.toDict(true, function (dict) {
                delete dict.key;
            });
            node.addChild(copyNode);
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Does the console say anything ? Does your `tree2` element have specified height and width ? (>can you actually see it when it's empty ?)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the dynatree source code (version 1.2.0), I found that it is not possible to add a node to an empty tree without the modification of the source code. This is because when you try to drop a source node to a target tree, it is actually drop a source node to/before/after a target node instead of target tree. Hence, dynatree will not work if there is no node in a tree.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```
var tree1Dragging = false,
    tree2Over = false;

$('#tree1').dynatree({
    dnd : {
        onDragStart : function(node) {
            tree1Dragging = true;
            return true;
        },
        onDragStop : function(node) {
            critDrag = false;

            if (tree2Over) {
                //TODO do your drop to tree2 process here (get the root and append the "node" to it for example)
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#tree2').dynatree({
    dnd : {
        onDragEnter : function(node, sourceNode) {
            return true;
        },
        onDrop : function(node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
            var copyNode = sourceNode.toDict(true, function(dict) {
                delete dict.key;
            });
            node.addChild(copyNode);
        }
    }
});

// Add mouse events to know when we are above the tree2 div
$("#tree2").mouseenter(function() {
    if (tree1Dragging) {
        tree2Over = true;
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
    tree2Over = false;
});
```

Comment: I simplified your solution. On event onDragStart fired i presumed flag DragOver = false;. If onDrop was fired then set DragOver = true;. On onDragStop i checked if (DragOver) { // drop on node } else { //drop on emptiness }. This works for me.